# how to fix preg_replace():Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting the check box values(multiple values) from view where user select the topics they are interested and store multiple values in a column in my database. So used serialize() to store them in my database. When i try to do that. It throws me the above mentioned error. I went through previous questions in Stackoverflow and did few changes like

```
$data = array(
'topics' => $post['topics'] ,);
```

to

```
$data = [
    'topics' => $post['topics'] ,];
```

Again it shows the same error , Here is my View

```
<div class="panel-body">
                   <center><h2> Select the topic you are interested in</h2></center><br>

                    <form enctype="multipart/formdata"class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/topicStore') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}


                         <center>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" value="sports"> Sports</input>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" value="education"> Education</input>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" value="family"> Family</input>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="topics[]" value="friends"> Friends</input></center><br>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Add topics 
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                      </div>
```

Here is my controller.

```
public function storeSelection(Request $request)
    {
        $post = $request->all();
        $val=\Validator::make($request->all(),

        [
           'topics' =>    'required',

        ]);


            if ($val ->fails()) 
                    {

                        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($val->errors());

                    }

            else
                    {
                        $data = array(

                            'topics' => $post['topics'] ,
                                     );



                        $topics = serialize($data);

                        $updatedata = DB::table('users')->where('name',\Auth::user()->name)
                        ->update($data);

                        if ($updatedata>0) {


                            return redirect('home');
                    }

}
    }
```

I want to save the array of data which i get from the view to a column in database. I have used `serialize()`. Are there any other better ways to do this ?

Comment: You could try with `implode`, like: `'topics' => implode(',', $post['topics'])`. This will store it as a comma-separated list in your database. Don't think you need serialize... anyway, you don't use `$topics` anywhere after setting it.

Comment: yes it worked , for 4 topics i can do this but if i want to store more than 100-200 topics then whats the possible solution ?

Comment: Why can you only do this for 4 topics?

Comment: If you want the *best* solution then that is not one where you put multiple topics into one column. In normalised, relational databases you'd store these in a separate table with a foreign key to the user to whom they belong (many to one).